# How to use custom images in a flutter app

Tags: flutter

I am just graduating and am working on my first app via an internship.  The school taught me ionic/angular but this customer wants to use flutter which I have no experience.  I have succeeded with demo apps running in chrome.

I am following this example [here](https://medium.com/swlh/flutter-custom-tab-indicator-for-tabbar-d72bbc6c9d0c).

But I get an error here trying to extend the Decoration class:

```
class CircleTabIndicator extends **Decoration** {
    final BoxPainter _painter;
```

It says:

> Classes can only extend other classes.
> Try specifying a different superclass, or removing the extends clause.

I am new to flutter so I do not understand why one class exists in a project and not the other.  I see no mention of an import or anything.  Also there only seems to be one type of project the *flutter create* produces so this is quite confusing.

What I really need to do is use custom icons in a tab app.  i have the tabs working with icons that I assume are default icons that come with flutter.  I used [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/flutter-tabs/) example and it worked flawlessly.

Comment: Are you importing `package:flutter/material.dart` at the top of your file?

Comment: @Enzo Nope, that was it, thanks.  If you want tom propose a solution I will mark it as correct otherwise I will have to do it.

Comment: Oh, ok. I'll post an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
```

at the top of the file you're declaring `CircleTabIndicator`.